# Xml Document Transform to find and replace &#xD;&#xA; values

Tags: .net, xml, newline, xdt-transform, xdt

I have an xml document that has a sql query in it.  Lets say it looks like this for example:

```
<commandText> Select ProductID, ProductName
              From   Product</commandText>
```

When this gets run through octopack and deployed (via octopus deploy) onto my server it looks like this:

```
<commandText> Select ProductID, ProductName&#xD;&#xA;     From   Product</commandText>
```

(The newline was converted to `&#xD;&#xA;`)

Is there an xml transform I can run after this change has been made to convert this back? (or at least remove the `&#xD;&#xA;`)

NOTE: My actual query is a complex merge statement, so I would rather not have it in more than one place.

Comment: What's the problem with having the entities in the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is WHITESPACE PRESERVE function of XmlDocument described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Second (and best) approach is to let XML decode automatically. You are using the wrong method to read out the select statement ;)

Comment: Okay, I think octopack encodes XML entities itself. When do you need the commandText to be without entities ? Usually XML entity encoding should not be a problem. Why do you need this to be without entities ?

Comment: I am realizing that this is mostly for human readability.  Probably not worth the work for just that...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but if I run this code (in Linqpad)

```
string x = "<commandText> Select ProductID, ProductName&#xD;&#xA;     From   Product</commandText>";
var wrapper = new StringReader(x);
XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(wrapper);
xr.MoveToContent();
xr.ReadOuterXml().Dump();
```

I get this literal output:

```
<commandText> Select ProductID, ProductName
     From   Product</commandText>
```

So if you are using an XmlReader on the server, there should not be any need to manipulate the entities via a transform. The XmlReader should interpret them just fine. Not sure if that was the issue though...